# xsl take path and substring the value

Tags: xslt

I have this xsl path that gives me a desired value:

```
/path/to/@value
```

Is there a way to combine this into a substring?

```
substring(/path/to/@value, 1, 5)
```

The preceding statement does not work because I'm not as familiar to xsl as I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it should work just fine:

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<path>
  <to value='123456'/>
</path>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <out>
      <xsl:value-of select='substring(/path/to/@value, 1, 5)'/>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another way is to use an intermediate variable:

```
<xsl:variable name='t' select='/path/to/@value'/>
<xsl:value-of select='substring( $t, 1, 5 )'/>
```

Comment: however, there's no way to do all that in the value-of select attribute value?

Comment: Apparently it works just as you suspect.. maybe the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: Grrrr! You're right, I was missing closing paren. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for thoroughness and insight

Comment: You're welcome! Sometimes all you need is an extra pair of eyes.